# A fair six-sided die is rolled repeatedly until the product of the rolls is square.

Tags: probability, statistics, markov-chains, dice

I'm stuck on this problem.

A fair six-sided die is rolled repeatedly. On average how long does it take until the first
time that the product of the numbers rolled is a square? (For example, if the first roll is
1 or 4, it takes just one roll; if the sequence begins 3, 2, 6, then it takes three rolls.)

I'm trying to use prime factors to get a solution, for instance if we don't roll a 1 or 4 first, rolling it again will not affect the chance of the next throw giving our product as a square, and we need an even number of 5s, the number of 2s + number of 6s to be even, and the number of 3s + number of 6s to be even.

I know I need to relate this to Markov chains somehow, but I'm stuck as to how.

Comment: You don't care about the prime exponents, just their parity.  So index a state by a triple $(a_1,a_2,a_3)$ where $a_i\in \{0,1\}$ and $a_1$ tracks the (parity of the) power of $2$ in the product, $a_2$ the power of $3$ and $a_3$ the power of $5$.  Now you have a nice finite collection of states to play with.

Comment: Cute problem. I wonder what the asymptotic behavior is for an $n$-sided die as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: I've now asked this generalization as a question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4813653/asymptotically-how-many-rolls-of-an-n-sided-die-will-multiply-to-a-perfect-sq).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by #lulu let Markov chain $X_n$ have $8$ states.
Let $a_1$ be the parity of power $2$,
Let $a_2$ be the parity of power $3$,
Let $a_3$ be the parity of power $5$.

Denote the states:

"1" if $(a_1,a_2,a_3)=(0,0,1)$

"2" if $(a_1,a_2,a_3)=(0,1,0)$

"3" if $(a_1,a_2,a_3)=(0,1,1)$

"4" if $(a_1,a_2,a_3)=(1,0,0)$

"5" if $(a_1,a_2,a_3)=(1,0,1)$

"6" if $(a_1,a_2,a_3)=(1,1,0)$

"7" if $(a_1,a_2,a_3)=(1,1,1)$

"8" if $(a_1,a_2,a_3)=(0,0,0)$ (the absorbing state).

The initial state after the first roll will be with "8" with probability $1/3$ (if you get 1 or 4), or "1","2","4", "6" each with probability $1/6$, i.e. $\pi=\left(\frac16,\frac16,0,\frac16,0,\frac16,0,\frac13\right)$.

The transition probability matrix will be then:
$$
P=\left[ \begin {array}{cccccccc} 
{\frac{1}{3}}&0&{\frac{1}{6}}&0&{
\frac{1}{6}}&0&{\frac{1}{6}}&{\frac{1}{6}}\\
0&{
\frac{1}{3}}&{\frac{1}{6}}&{\frac{1}{6}}&0&{\frac{1}{6}}&0&{\frac{1}{6
}}\\ 
{\frac{1}{6}}&{\frac{1}{6}}&{\frac{1}{3}}&0&{
\frac{1}{6}}&0&{\frac{1}{6}}&0\\ 0&{\frac{1}{6}}&0&{
\frac{1}{3}}&{\frac{1}{6}}&{\frac{1}{6}}&0&{\frac{1}{6}}
\\ 
{\frac{1}{6}}&0&{\frac{1}{6}}&{\frac{1}{6}}&{
\frac{1}{3}}&0&{\frac{1}{6}}&0\\ 0&{\frac{1}{6}}&0&{
\frac{1}{6}}&0&{\frac{1}{3}}&{\frac{1}{6}}&{\frac{1}{6}}
\\ 
{\frac{1}{6}}&0&{\frac{1}{6}}&0&{\frac{1}{6}}&{
\frac{1}{6}}&{\frac{1}{3}}&0\\ {}0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1
\end {array} \right] 
$$
The sub-matrix $[1..7,1..7]$ is $P_0$ and then the expected time to reach the absorbing state "8" from state $i$ is given by $\mu_i$ where $\mu$ is
$$
\mu=({\bf I}-P_0)^{-1} \begin{bmatrix}
1\\1\\1\\1\\1\\1\\1
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
12\\ 10\\ 14\\ 10\\ 14\\ 10\\ 14
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where ${\bf I}$ is the $7\times7$ identity matrix.

It takes one roll to get the first number, and after that the expected time to get to full square is 0 with probability 1/3 (if you got "4" or "1") and otherwise $\mu_i$ with probability $\pi_i$, $i=1,...,7$. Consequently the answer is $1+7=8$.

Answer (score 0):

Python code to back it up:

```
import random
import math

SIMULATIONS = 10000

def is_square(n):
    if math.sqrt(n).is_integer():
        return False # for the while loop to continue until square (while True)
    else:
        return True

def multiply(lst):
    product = 1
    for element in lst:
        product = product * element
    return product

def simulation():
    expected_rolls = []
    for _ in range(SIMULATIONS):
        rounds = 0
        rolls = []
        dice = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
        if len(rolls) == 0:
            rolls.append(random.choice(dice))
            rounds += 1
        while is_square(multiply(rolls)):
            rolls.append(random.choice(dice))
            rounds += 1
        expected_rolls.append(rounds)
    print(f"The expected number of rolls is: {sum(expected_rolls)/len(expected_rolls)}")

simulation()
```

Very interesting problem!