# Asymptotically, how many rolls of an $n$-sided die will multiply to a perfect square for the first time?

Tags: probability, prime-numbers

This is a generalization of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4813499/a-fair-six-sided-die-is-rolled-repeatedly-until-the-product-of-the-rolls-is-squa), which I found amusing. My generalization is as follows:

> You have an $n$-sided die. You roll at least once, and keep rolling until the product of all the rolls equals a perfect square. For instance, the following roll sequences are complete and don't contain any complete proper prefixes:
>
> - $2$-$1$-$6$-$3$, yielding $36 = 6^2$
> - the single roll $4 = 2^2$
> - $5$-$2$-$2$-$4$-$5$, yielding $400 = 20^2$
>
> Let $r(n)$ be the expected number of rolls needed to multiply to a perfect square for the first time. The quoted question asks for $r(6)$. I'd like to find the asymptotic behavior of $r(n)$ as $n \to \infty$, as closely as possible.

I don't *see* a duplicate, but I'm not $100$ percent sure there isn't one. I have a simple approach (which I haven't completed working on yet) based on a continuous approximation to $\pi(n)$, the prime-counting function, but I have a vague suspicion that there's something better out there. Any thoughts?

Comment: Intuitively, it seems like for large $n$, it will usually become 'well-mixed' much quicker than it is likely to return to 0, so the initial state matters less as $n$ gets larger. I wonder if this means the expected time is asymptotically just proportional to the number of states.

Comment: There are $2^{\pi(n)}$ relevant states (for each prime up to $n$, is the exponent in the cumulative product even or odd), so presumably the expectation should be roughly this size.

Comment: I’d say a bit larger, because large primes (say 17 or 19 on a 20-sided die ) wouldn’t come often and change rarely.